# Deleting an email using powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

I want to delete an email from Exchange serveur and then from the mailbox received items,so I used this following powershell command but after a while , powershell_ise crashes and it closes

```
Search-Mailbox -Identity "Khalil Med" -SearchQuery 'Subject:"Phishing"' -DeleteContent
```

Comment: Pro-tip: Don't use the ISE.

Comment: okey , I opened Windows PowerShell and the command worked but the email still appears in the receiver mailbox( Khalil Med)

Comment: @mamadou Any resolution with this? I'm having the same problem. Any way I run Search-Mailbox crashes the shell.

Answer (score 0):

I live in the ISE daily and sometimes VSCode as needed and I do this sort of thing regularly in the ISE and VSCode, neither have crashed on me for this kind of use case. Yet, environments can differ. I find it hard to understand how running this simple request would crash the ISE, as it's not doing anything $psISE / ISE GUI specific.

Are you doing this on the Exchange server directly, or via Explicit or Implicit remote session from your admin workstation?

Also, make sure you have the RBAC role to perform this...

```
Get-ManagementRoleAssignment -Role 'Mailbox Import Export'
New-ManagementRoleAssignment -Role 'Mailbox Import Export' -User 'Administrator'
```

... and make sure you are getting something to act on, meaning actual emails using...

```
Search-Mailbox -Identity 'HostMaster TestUser' -SearchQuery "Subject:test" -EstimateResultOnly
```

If the response from the above is '0', then well, you now know why the -DeleteContent did not actually work.

As a sanity check. Rather than looking at one account. Look at all accounts to see if you are getting any hits on anyone..

```
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | 
Search-Mailbox -SearchQuery 'Subject:test' -EstimateResultOnly -Force | 
Where-Object -Property ResultItemsCount -gt 0
```